# Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Restore error .mdf-file

Tags: sql-server-2005, restore

I tried to execute the following query:

```
RESTORE DATABASE TESTDB FROM DISK = <path of file> WITH REPLACE
```

The result was this execption:

> ```
> The file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> ```
>
> Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\BCS.mdf'
>   cannot be overwritten.  It is being
>   used by database ' @databaseName '.
>   File 'BCS' cannot be restored to
>   'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\BCS.mdf'.
>   Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid
>   location for the file. The file
>   'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\BCS_log.LDF'
>   cannot be overwritten.  It is being
>   used by database ' @databaseName '.
>   File 'BCS_log' cannot be restored to
>   'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\BCS_log.LDF'.
>   Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid
>   location for the file. Problems were
>   identified while planning for the
>   RESTORE statement. Previous messages
>   provide details. RESTORE DATABASE is
>   terminating abnormally.

The problem: BCS.mdf and BCS_log.LDF doesen't exist in the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does that directory exist - c:\program files\microsoft sql server\mssql.1\ data ?

This is a common problem when moving databases from one server to another via the backup method.... either create the directories required with the appropriate permissions, or use the WITH MOVE option as hinted.

Answer (score 0):

if the backup file from difference computer, it may be get path for the last computer. you must set the path base on path on your local. or you can use back up and restore database wizard in sql server 2005.